# Slow Sitecore platform due to lot of data in Mongo DB

Tags: xdb

We observed very bad performance of Sitecore Digital Platform. Applications like List manager, indexing are very very slow. Contact data and corresponding properties within contact are getting increased. Can we create multiple collections like SQL table structure for Contacts? if yes then do we need to make any customization to handle inbuilt Sitecore functionalities like segmentation.

Is there any performance tuning guideline for mongo/xDb?

Comment: Can you specify which version you are working with? This will help people guide you down the right path, as Sitecore 9.x and Sitecore 8.x have very different architectures for experience data storage.

Comment: We are using Sitecore 8.2 Initial version.